# table(s) structure to obtain a specific array format

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently designing a db schema to obtain an array like this one:

```
[{
                    "name": "Sprint 0",
                    "desc": "Analysis",
                    "values": [{
                        "from": "/Date(1320192000000)/",
                        "to": "/Date(1322401600000)/",
                        "label": "Design",
                        "customClass": "ganttGreen"
                    }]
                },{
                    name: " ", //this is again Sprint 0 so make it empty not to display repetitive data
                    desc: "Scoping",
                    values: [{
                        from: "/Date(1322611200000)/",
                        to: "/Date(1323302400000)/",
                        label: "Scoping",
                        customClass: "ganttRed"
                    }]
                },{
                    name: "Sprint 1",
                    desc: "Development",
                    values: [{
                        from: "/Date(1323802400000)/",
                        to: "/Date(1325685200000)/",
                        label: "Development",
                        customClass: "ganttGreen"
                    }]
                },{
                    name: " ",
                    desc: "Showcasing",
                    values: [{
                        from: "/Date(1325685200000)/",
                        to: "/Date(1325695200000)/",
                        label: "Showcasing",
                        customClass: "ganttBlue"
                    }]
                },{
                    name: "Sprint 2",
                    desc: "Development",
                    values: [{
                        from: "/Date(1326785200000)/",
                        to: "/Date(1325785200000)/",
                        label: "Development",
                        customClass: "ganttGreen"
                    }]
                }]
```

It is a collection of tasks to be displayed. It is a reverse engineering exercise since I am using a plugin to display data and it expects this structure of data.
The data structure would be like that:
foreach  "name" you will have multiple "desc" values and for each desc you can have multiples "values"

What would be the most efficient table(s) structure to obtain this doing as much as possible on mysql side? (I think that the part where I replace with empty the "name" value if it is the same as the previuous must be on PHP)

So far I have these tables

```
GANTT_PHASES
    id  nome                progetto
---------------------------------------
    1   Setup di progetto   1
    2   Blueprint           1
    3   Realizzazione       1
    4   Test                1
    5   Go Live             1
```

and this one

```
GANTT   
id  phaseID date_to                 date_from            ordine descr   label   customClass progetto
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   1       2018-10-05 02:00:00     2018-10-03 02:00:00     1   pippo   pippo1  ganttGreen  1
2   1       2018-10-05 02:00:00     2018-10-03 02:00:00     2   pluto   pippo1  ganttGreen  1
```

the query:

```
SELECT nome, descr, label, customClass, date_from, date_to 
FROM `gantt_fasi` LEFT JOIN gantt on gantt_fasi.id= gantt.phaseID 
WHERE gantt_fasi.progetto=1
```

will produce the following output:

```
nome                descr   label   customClass date_from               date_to     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Setup di progetto   pippo   pippo1  ganttGreen  2018-10-03 02:00:00     2018-10-05 02:00:00
Setup di progetto   pluto   pippo1  ganttGreen  2018-10-03 02:00:00     2018-10-05 02:00:00
Blueprint           NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL                    NULL
Realizzazione       NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL                    NULL
Test                NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL                    NULL
Go Live             NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL                    NULL
```

and then I go down with PHP to create the array. Anything I can improve on this approach?

Comment: What do you suggest in the first place? I realize what you’re asking for, but what you already have (or planning to), and what are your for’s and against it?

Comment: The point actually is that mysql will always produce a flat array and I need to transform it in a multidimensional one. If you don't consider the value part then it's very straightforward. To obtain this now I have to do a huge iteration in PHP and that's not efficient in terms of performance (a bunch of foreach and ifs)

Comment: Are you aware of cross-table relationships that can be done via JOIN, thus allowing you to construct hierarchical or multidimensional data structures? Sure, it’s not going to be as easy as a single query, but at least it will be structured and easy to understand, not mentioning the storage and retrieval.

Comment: obviuosly yes. But the query will always produce a two dimensional table output with as many sources as you want. And not a multidimensional one

Comment: Then you can retrieve data in two iterations: first, get top-level objects by IDs, then second-level by parent IDs, and then construct a structure you require. If that doesn’t work out well, you might look into MongoDB type of database that stores JSON objects.

Comment: that's what I was telling you a couple of commets ago. And I am looking for a way to improve that approach that is basic and not performance wise

Comment: Your description doesn't match with the code. From the code I see 2 entities: Entity Task with attributes name and desc. Entity Value with attributes from, to, label and customClass. And the relation: Task has many Values. But your description suggests: name has many descs and desc has many values. So which one is actually correct?

Comment: It's a hierarchy structure. so for a name you can have multiple desc and for each name and desc pair you have at least a nested array with some attributes for that pair (from, to, label and customClass).